# Is it possible to provide different Xresources colors to different terminal apps?

Tags: colors, theme, rxvt, x-resources

When using a terminal that supports more than 16 colors (such as urxvt), it it possible to provide different colors to different applications running in the same terminal after another? For example, my vim theme looks best when `background` and `color0` are set to the same value, while htop looks best when they are different.

Comment: Write a wrapper or alias that changes colors using ANSI codes, then calls the application?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks. Do you have a reference on how to chance the colors using ANSI codes?

Answer (score 1):

xterm has this feature:

```
   +dc     This option enables the escape sequence to change dynamic
           colors.  The option sets the dynamicColors option to “true”.
```

Check for more info: https://github.com/sos4nt/dynamic-colors

Comment: Thanks. Keeping this open to see if someone knows a solution for urxvt, or even a terminal agnostic one.